# How to return to the begining of file in C++/CLI?

Tags: c++-cli

I don't know how to return to start of a file.

In C++ I can just close and then open file again.

But there is no "read_file->Open()"

```
StreamReader^ read_file = gcnew StreamReader(path + "\\" + file);
//CODE
read_file->Close();
//And now what to open it again or go to begining?
```

I didn't try anything because I just don't know.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.discardbuffereddata?view=net-7.0

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new `StreamReader`, i.e.

```
auto read_file = gcnew StreamReader(path + "\\" + file);
auto line = read_file->ReadLine();
read_file->Close();
//re-open
read_file = gcnew StreamReader(path + "\\" + file);
```